# Busy Indicator next to button

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I want to put a busy indicator to the right of a button so I tried using BusyIndicator that is part of Silverlight Toolkit.  However, I quickly found out it's not really designed for this type of use.  So anyone know where I can find a small indicator button that spins to the right of a button to indicate work is being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one [here](http://chrisa.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/a-wait-indicator-in-silverlight/) and another [here](http://live.mscommunity.net/blogs/domagojpavlesic/archive/2010/07/04/circular-progress-bar-in-silverlight.aspx), and [another](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/busyindicator.aspx).

Comment: 1st link) The company I work for has it blocked so I can't view it. 2nd link) This is not completely what I'm looking for.  Might be able to modify it to get work.  However if I can find something out of the box it would be better.  3rd link)  That is using Silverlight Toolkit which disables a control.  I'm looking for something more like this #5 on this link [link](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138028/ProgressIndicator)

Comment: @Michael - The first link describes one like that. The source links to [here](http://www.box.net/shared/6o8kg8j6f4), which may not be blocked. Or you can view the [Google Cache version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:tcW9ZyQ7-r0J:chrisa.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/a-wait-indicator-in-silverlight/+A+Wait+Indicator+In+Silverlight&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com).

Comment: They block the cache version too.  However the source link did work.  I'm checking it out now.